# gem install not creating lib/

Tags: ruby, rubygems

There's only one error I get when installing my custom gem: `File not found: lib ERROR:  While generating documentation`

The install continues and says `gem installed successfully`. However, when I `require 'boxes'` I get `LoadError: no such file to load -- boxes` and when I look into the gem directory I notice that there is no `lib/` folder in the installed gem. I'm not sure why this is or how to debug it. Any pointers? Below is my gemspec file.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'boxes/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  gem.authors       = ["Name"]
  gem.email         = ["http://somedomain.com"]
  gem.description   = %q{Boxes, a Sass framework}
  gem.summary       = %q{Boxes is a modular Sass-based framework that is heavily configurable, extremely modular and works as a Sass and a CSS Framework}
  gem.homepage      = "http://somedomain.com"

  gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($\)
  gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  gem.test_files    = gem.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  gem.name          = "boxes"
  gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
  gem.version       = Boxes::VERSION
  gem.license       = "MIT"

  gem.add_dependency "sass", [">= 3.2.0"]
  gem.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

I'm new at ruby, and I'm just creating my first gem here, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that on line 1, you're defining "lib" as "../lib", though in `gem.require_paths` "lib" is in the current directory. Is that true?

Another thing to look for is that lib is not in .gitignore, as you're using `git ls-files` for defining `gem.files`

## edit

Noticed in your gemfile that you're using ruby 1.8.7, make sure you require 'rubygems' before you require your gem

Comment: lib is not excluded and '..lib' (although that baffles me as well) is correct, it's taken straight from the gemspec that bundler generates `bundle gem somegem`

Comment: Sorry, just re-read that, it's correct as it will end up as `./lib`. My bad.

Comment: How will it end up as ./lib ?